# Using Office365 Excel array formulas, how to repeat the previous value if the current value is empty, blank, N/A, or an error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, array-formulas

In MS Excel Office365, how can an array formula use the previous value to fill in data that is missing or an error?

For example, if the data in column A on rows 1 to 5 is 1,,2,3,err then an array formula in column C using =a1:a5 results in the second entry being empty and the last entry being err.

The result should be 1,1,2,3,3 in columns C.  The first cell is always a valid value (not blank and not an error).

I've tried many combinations of formulas including iferror() and offset() to point to the previous cell.  Nothing has worked so far with an array formula.  No VBA please, only an array type formula.

Comment: Filling the wrong value, but an initial idea was something like `=LET(data,A1:A5,bools,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,NOT(OR(ISBLANK(x),ISERROR(x))))),IF(bools,data,XLOOKUP(TRUE,bools,data,,,-1)))`. May be a dead end.

Comment: Just tried it.  That's very close.  However it's only using the very last value to fill in the missing cells.  So the result is 1,3,2,3,3.  Need 1,1,2,3,3.  I will work with the concept some more to see if it can work.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.  Thanks to @BigBen for inspiring it.

```
=SCAN(0,A1:A5,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(IFERROR(v,"")="",a,v)))
```

Scan the data which processes the lambda function one value at a time.  If the value is blank or an error (which is converted to a blank by the IFERROR() function) then use the previous result from the lambda function.

Instead of a range (A1:A5), the data can also be an array reference like C1# or any formula which results in an array.

End result is 1,1,2,3,3.  This will work for any number of blank or error values.  So 1,,,,,,2,err,err,3 results in 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3.